# Fullcalendar - How to get single resource when click on event multiple resources

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using Fullcalendar to render a event with multiple resources. It shows event for each resources like image below. How can I get resouce information when click on event of this resource.
For example:

- Click on event 1: => get information of resource NH3
- Click on event 2: => get information of resource nh4

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you handle the [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) callback, you can get the resource ID from the event details provided in the callback (i.e. `info.event.resourceId`). Once you've got the resource ID, you can use [getResourceById](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getResourceById) to get the other details of the resource.

Comment: Thank for your reply @Adyson, due to this event has multiple resources, so in eventClick callback, I just can get only resourceIds list not a specific resource for correspond resource column.

Comment: Ah ok. That was perhaps a detail you should have made clear before. So you want to understand which copy of the event was clicked on? I don't think that's possible, unfortunately.